# How is plain text modified when set through innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, contenteditable

When setting `innerHTML = '\r\n'`, it seems like browsers may end up writing `'\n'`.
This introduces a gap between the actual plain text content of the element and what I have been keeping track of.

- Is this a rather isolated problem or are there many more potential changes I should be aware of?
- How to ensure that the content of the text nodes matches exactly what I'm trying to write?

I guess it's possible just not to use innerHTML, build the nodes and the text nodes and insert them, but it's much less convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read a string from `innerHTML`, it's **not** the string you wrote, it's created completely from scratch by converting the DOM structure of the element into HTML that will (mostly) create it. That means lots of things happen:

1. Newlines are normalized
2. Character entities are normalized
3. Quotes are normalized
4. Tags are normalized
5. Tags are *corrected* if the text you supplied defined an invalid HTML structure

...and so on. You can't expect a round-trip through the DOM to result in exactly the same string.

**If** you're dealing with pure text content, you can use `textContent` instead:

```js
const x = document.getElementById("x");
const str = "CRLF: \r\n";
x.textContent = str;
console.log(x.textContent === str);
```

```html
<div id="x"></div>
```

I can't 100% vouch for there being no newline normalization (or come to that, Unicode normalization; you might run the string through [`normalize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize) first) although a quick test with a Chromium-based browser, Firefox, and iOS Safari suggested there wasn't, but certainly most of the issues with `innerHTML` don't occur.

Comment: I wasn't actually reading through innerHTML. The text was written through innerHTML and read by parsing the text nodes. But it seems the process you described still applies when writing! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: By the way the problem came from trying to keep the text content intact while also adding tags. So I can't use textContent in a straightforward manner. I'd be left with the need to build independently all the nodes (cf. first message).

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not an isolated issue as it is expected behavior since you are writing HTML using the innerHTML tag.
2. if you want to make sure your text matches exactly what you are writing including new lines and spaces use the Html **pre** tag and write your text node there.

**pre** tag description: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp

Comment: If you keep using innerHTML, pre doesn't seem to change much.
Quick comparison here: https://codepen.io/ghostinpeace/pen/VwdrMON
But thanks for pointing it out!